# PysimpleGUI combo source from dataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe, pysimplegui

please advise my project to the attched picture(error&problem)

1.combo source==>one of column in dataframe: need to fix, please help me

2.last record No(ExNo) in excel ==>should to reflect on the input screen as ExNo

3.int(['Total'])-int(['VAT']) ==>error

[image]

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

# Add some color to the window
sg.theme('DarkTeal9')

coa_file = 'D:\92Python\Acdb\coa.xlsx'
coa_data = pd.read_excel(coa_file, sheet_name="coa", skiprows = 1, index_col=False)
coa_df = pd.DataFrame(coa_data) #.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
coa_df1 =coa_df.iloc[:,[0,1]] <--error
ExNo = 1
#print(coa_df1)

EXCEL_FILE = 'D:\92Python\Acdb\Data_Entry.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(EXCEL_FILE)

layout = [
    [sg.Text('Please fill out the following fields:')],
    [sg.Text('Expense No', size=(15,1), justification= 'left', key='ExNo')], <--error
    [sg.Text('Date', size=(15,1)), sg.InputText(key='Date'), sg.CalendarButton("Date", close_when_date_chosen=True, target="Date", location=(0,0), no_titlebar=False)],
    [sg.Text('COA', size=(15,1)), sg.InputCombo(coa_df1, key='COA',size=(50,1))],
    [sg.Text('Supplier', size=(15,1)), sg.InputText(key='Supplier')],
    [sg.Text('Total', size=(15,1)), sg.InputText(key='Total')],
    [sg.Text('VAT', size=(15,1)), sg.InputText(key='VAT')],
    #[sg.Text('Amount', size=(15,1), justification= 'left', key='Amount')],
    [sg.Text('Paid', size=(15,1)),
                            sg.Checkbox('Cash', key='Cash'),
                            sg.Checkbox('CreditCard', key='CreditCard'),
                            sg.Checkbox('Bank', key='Bank'),
                            sg.Checkbox('Owners', key='Owners')],
    [sg.Text('Description', size=(15,1)), sg.InputText(key='Desc')],
    [sg.Text('No. of Children', size=(15,1)), sg.Spin([i for i in range(0,16)],
                                                       initial_value=0, key='Children')],
    [sg.Submit(), sg.Button('Clear'), sg.Exit()]
]

window = sg.Window('Simple data entry form', layout, no_titlebar=False, location=(10,10), size=(800,600), keep_on_top=True)
#window['Date'].bind("<Return>", "_Enter")

def clear_input():
    for key in values:
        window[key]('')
    return None


while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
        break
    if event == 'Clear':
        clear_input()
    if event == 'Submit':
        #amount = float(int(['Total'])-int(['VAT']))
        #window['Amount'].Update(amount)
        new_record = pd.DataFrame(values, index=[0])
        df = pd.concat([df, new_record], ignore_index=True)
        df.to_excel(EXCEL_FILE, index=False)
        sg.popup('Data saved!')
        clear_input()
window.close()
```

Comment: 1. combo source `coa_df1 =coa_df.iloc[:,1].to_list()`, 2. last record No(ExNo) `len(coa_df1)-1` if count from 0, 3. `int(values['Total'])-int(values['VAT'])`

Comment: Very appriciate your help. thanks

Comment: 2.last record No(ExNo): len(coa_df1)-1==>good but How can I connect to layout? 
I did like this " [sg.Text('Expense No', size=(15,1)), sg.InputText(key='ExNo')]," but not work.

Comment: `[sg.Text('Expense No', size=(15,1)), sg.InputText(str(ExNo), key='ExNo')]` where `ExNo = len(coa_df1)-1`